# Insert the output of a shell-command directly into a tmux pane

Tags: shell, copy-paste, tmux

My goal is to replicate the middle-mouse copy-paste functionality in linux.

I can display the output of this clipboard in a pane via:

```
bind-key -T root MouseDown2Pane run-shell "xclip -selection primary -o"
```

I'd like to directly insert this output into the pane (i.e. similar to `send-keys`) but I don't see a way to link the 2 commands together.

I'm running tmux version 2.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by redirecting the output of the shell command into a (temporary file), then inserting the contents of that file directly into the pane using the tmux `load-buffer` and `paste-buffer` commands:

```
bind-key -T root MouseDown2Pane run-shell "xclip -selection primary -o >~/.tmux-buffer-tmp" \; load-buffer -b tmp-copy-buffer ~/.tmux-buffer-tmp \; paste-buffer -b tmp-copy-buffer -d \; run-shell -b "rm ~/.tmux-buffer-tmp"
```

Explaining each step:

- `run-shell "xclip -selection primary -o >~/.tmux-buffer-tmp"` uses the xclip utility to insert the contents of the clipboard into a temporary file
- `load-buffer -b tmp-copy-buffer ~/.tmux-buffer-tmp` loads the contents of the above file into a tmux buffer
- `paste-buffer -b tmp-copy-buffer -d` pastes those contents direty into the active pane (and deletes the temporary buffer so that the state of the buffers is unchanged by the mouse click)
- `run-shell -b "rm ~/.tmux-buffer-tmp"` removes the temporary file.

Comment: In addition to the centre button pasting primary,  I also used this mehod to bind `CONTROL+v` to paste the clipboard: `bind-key -T root C-v run-shell....`

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this that doesn't require a temporary file is:

```
bind-key -T root MouseDown2Pane run-shell 'tmux set-buffer -b x-clip "$(xsel -op)"' \; paste-buffer -b x-clip -d
```

Break down:

- `bind-key -T root MouseDown2Pane`: Bind to a middle mouse click  on a pane in the root key table (which applies when you aren't in copy mode and haven't pressed the prefix)
- `run-shell 'tmux set-buffer -b x-clip "$(xsel -op)"'`: This is a little hacky, but it runs the `set-buffer` tmux command in a shell with another tmux command. This is so we can expand the output of the `xsel` command to get the clipboard contents
- `paste-buffer -b x-clip -d`: Pastes the contents of the buffer, and deletes it.

Another way to do it:

```
bind-key -T root MouseDown2Pane run-shell 'xclip -o | tmux load-buffer -bxclip -' \; paste-buffer -bxclip -d
```